# Getting values from an edittext and comparing it to a set variable

Tags: java, android, math

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here. When I call checkAnswer(), it crashes the program. Here are the variables and my button.

```
int random1;
int random2;

 int Min = 1;
 int Max = 4;
 int score = 0;
 int correctAnswer;
 String question;

String i;
String a;

  editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Edit);
   editTextEquation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.equation);
  scoredisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);


@Override
public void onClick(View v){
switch(v.getId()){
case R.id.keypad_hash:

    getQuestion();
   checkAnswer(editText.getText().toString());

    break;
```

I'm attempting to extract the value of the user input edittext and then comparing it with the answer.

```
 public void getQuestion(){

    random1 = (int)(Math.random()*100);
    random2 = (int)(Math.random()*10);

    int i1 = Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1));

    if(i1 == 1){
    question = (random1 + "+" + random2);
    correctAnswer = random1 + random2;
    editTextEquation.setText(question);
    }
    if(i1 == 2){
    question = (random1 + "-" +random2);
    correctAnswer = random1 - random2;
    editTextEquation.setText(question);

    }
    if(i1 == 3){
    question = random1 + "/" +random2;
    correctAnswer = random1 / random2;
    editTextEquation.setText(question);

    }
    if(i1 == 4){
    question = (random1 + "*" +random2);
    correctAnswer = random1 * random2;
    editTextEquation.setText(question);


    }



}

public void checkAnswer(){
    i = editText.getText().toString();
    Integer a = Integer.valueOf(i);
    if (a == correctAnswer){

        score++;
        scoredisplay.setText(score);

    }
    else{

        score--;
        scoredisplay.setText(score);
    }




}
```

Comment: What's the error message you get?

Answer (score 3):

You should call `setText` with a `String`. If you call it with an int it tries to find the string that matches that id. So it should probably be:

```
scoredisplay.setText("" + score);
```

Also, compare strings using `.equals`, not `==`, as `==` compares references, not content.

Comment: ah yeah, that's it, thank you. One more thing, do you know why the answer is always treated as wrong. I enter the correct answer, but the score counter decreases every time.

Comment: This is the "Also part" in my answer.

Comment: The answers are being stored as int's. Should I not try to convert the edittext input into integer and then compare the two?

Comment: That's fine too. but if you compare strings, use equals.

Comment: its still treating every answer as wrong, whether I try comparing strings or ints?

Comment: Print the values to log and see what the problem is.

Comment: Not quite sure how to do that. I've tried printing correctAnswer to the screen and thats right. I must have something wrong with the extraction/conversion of the input edittext thats compared with it. public void checkAnswer(){
        int mm;
      //answer = editText.getText().toString();
      mm = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
      
         if (mm == correctAnswer){
      
      score++;
      scoredisplay.setText("" + correctAnswer);

Answer (score 0):

You are passing parameters to your checkAnswer() method, and it isn't expecting any.

Either make your method call to check answer have no parameters like so:

```
getQuestion();
checkAnswer();
```

or change your checkAnswer method to accept a string parameter. Like this:

```
public void checkAnswer(String answer){
    i = answer;
    Integer a = Integer.valueOf(i);
    if (a == correctAnswer){

        score++;
        scoredisplay.setText(score);

    }
    else{

        score--;
        scoredisplay.setText(score);
    }




}
```

Comment: Can I pass it the value of the edittext using - checkAnswer(editText.getText().toString());

Comment: I'm still getting a problem where it treats every answer as wrong? any ideas? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you getting any compile error! , or post the latest code of yours... checkAnswer(String) you are calling is different first of all from checkAnswer() defined below.. you also haven't shown editText declaration..

Also it would break at

```
Integer a = Integer.valueOf(i);
```

if i(edittext) has any string value,, you should catch exception there.. and use i.trim() for proper handling.

And provide atleast stacktrace and proper code to let us know the problem...